# 編集のロールバックと通報のリセット

Tags: サポート

[ファイル一覧を更新日時でソートするこのプログラムを、もっと簡潔にできないか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9672/)
[C#でAWS S3に画像アップロード、URL取得](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14498/)

など、同じ質問者による質問について、本人により質問の大部分を削除する編集がおこなわれています。

質問の意味がわからなくなるような編集もあるので、ロールバックしようかと思いましたが、ロールバックのリンクに

> 現在のリビジョンをこの投稿のバージョンに設定して、「暴言」の通報をリセットする

と表示されているのに気付きました。

この「通報をリセットする」というのはどういう意味なのでしょうか。

- 今現在、誰かがこの質問について「通報」した状態
- ロールバックをおこなうことでこの「通報」を無効に出来る

ということでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

既にそのような通報がされているかどうかは文言に反映されません。もしあれば、です。

例えば第三者による編集によってスパムリンクや暴言などが追加された場合、それに対する通報はロールバックとともに取り消されてしかるべきです。これが自動的に行われます。

参考

- [What is a 'rollback'? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17038/286934)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/286934)

Comment: 文言は見直した方がいいような気がしますが動作としては理解しました。

Comment: そうですね、ロールバック自体の説明としてもわかりにくいので `投稿の内容をこのリビジョンまで戻す (もし「失礼又は不快」通報があれば、その通報も取り消されます)` と訳を変更してみました。